# ADA - I got 2 Bubble sorting algorithm but only one works

Tags: algorithm, sorting, generics, ada

As the title says I have two algorithm for bubble sorting but the one I wrote is not working in all cases.

This is the code that works in every case

```
procedure Sort( t: in out Item_array) is
   Finished : Boolean;
   tmp: Item;
begin
loop
  Finished := True;
  for J in t'First..Index'Pred(t'Last) loop
     if t(J) < t(Index'Succ(J)) then
        Finished := False;
        tmp := t(Index'Succ(J));
        t(Index'Succ(J)) := t(J);
        t(J) := tmp;
     end if;
  end loop;
exit when Finished;
end loop;
end Sort;
```

And here is my code which is not working with the following array (2,4,3,2,2,5). I assume It is because of multiple '2's.

```
procedure Sort( t: in out Item_array) is
   I : Index := t'Last;
   CS: Index := t'First;
   tmp: Item;
begin
   while I >= Index'Succ(t'First) loop
      for J in t'First..Index'Pred(I) loop
         if t(J) < t(Index'Succ(J)) then
            tmp := t(Index'Succ(J));
            t(Index'Succ(J)) := t(j);
            t(j) := tmp;
            CS := J;
         end if;
      end loop;
      I := CS;
   end loop;
end Sort;
```

In both cases the "<" operator is a function template parameter, not a regular "less" or "more" operator.
And this is how I call the function.

```
function Asc(A,B : in Integer) return Boolean is (A > B); // Sorting function

procedure Sort_Asc is new Sort(Item=>Integer, 
                                Index=>Positive, 
                                Item_Array=>Int_Array,
                                "<"=>Asc);

x : Int_Array := (2,4,3,2,2,5);
Sort_Asc(x);
```

If I use the second algorithm, It'll stuck in an infinite loop.
             //Please don't mind my english.

Comment: Is it possible that the infinite loop is due to the `CS` variable not changing once the array is sorted, and therefore `I` never changes? You might consider changing that line `I := CS` to `I := Succ(I)`. Or should that be `Pred(I)`? Whichever way you're going. (It's been too many years since I even looked at Ada.)

Comment: @JimMischel You might be right! But I declared as `CS : Index :=  t'First` ,so if the array is all sorted I must be `t'First` therefore the while loop should broke.

Comment: Can you think of a better name for `CS`? One which explains what it means, what it’s for.  And `I`, come to that.

Comment: Seems like it'd be trivial to give my suggestion a try. If it works, then you know that the problem is with the way you're modifying `I` in that loop. I *think* you're trying to use that `CS` variable to do some kind of optimization, although as @SimonWright points out, it's rather difficult to say for sure.

Comment: And, by the way, if `I` is equal to `t'First`, then it looks like your loop won't break because your condition is `>=`, not `>`. But then, I could be misunderstanding the Ada syntax.